# Is calque equal to literal translation？

Tags: translation, borrowing

Calque is a way of borrowing words from another language. In this process, there's a direct translation of the elements of a word into the borrowing language.

Is calque equal to literal translation?

Answer (score 1):

No. Calquing is the use of literal translation of a word or phrase to refer to the same thing that word or phrase refers to. So literal translation alone wouldn't be a calque.

Comment: so If I understand correctly, literal translation is only a tool used in calquing?

Comment: More precisely, calquing is the process of _using a literal translation as a new word in the language_. A calque is a type of loan word, one that exists as part of the lexicon in the target language. You can make a literal one-off translation of a word and use it to refer to the same thing the source refers to without it being a calque – it only becomes a calque if it becomes established in the target language.

Comment: (Heh, just noticed I myself called it a ‘word’ here, immediately after pointing out in another comment that calques aren’t necessarily single words. Well done, me. Using a literal translation as an _established entity_ in the target language was what I really meant.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I get it:)

Answer (score 1):

No. Literal translation refers to full sentences or texts while calque refers to a *translation unit* (word or multi-word expression). You can do literal translation without ever using a single calque, and you can use a calque of a certain word in a non-literal translation.

Comment: Who says a calque must be a single word? Expressions are calqued all the time (e.g., ‘it goes without saying’ is a calque of _ça va sans dire_, ‘long time no see’ is a calque of 好久不见).

Comment: OK, this looks relevant, I will replace the term *word* by *translation unit* which comprises multi-words expressions.